# Getting another opportunity to resurrect a ghost

Tags: the-sims-3

My partner died. I waited 3 days then I had the opportunity to bring him back to life at the science lab, but I accidentally declined the offer. Is there any way to get that opportunity back?

I really want him as a playable ghost. I researched it a lot but it seems I'm the only person stupid enough to have declined it.

I tried befriending someone and putting their needs on static once I moved them in. It's been a week. I have also tried working at the science lab and clicking to make all events happen and opportunities, but nothing works. I really don't want to give up.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>You can resurrect a Sim by having their ghost eat Ambrosia [Here's some more info](http://www.carls-sims-3-guide.com/skills/cooking/ambrosia.php)</strike>

**EDIT:** As msg45f has pointed out - my answer was a bit off the mark -

The only way to make a playable ghost is through the Science lab route which isn't a repeatable event. The Ambrosia mentioned in my original point will bring a playable ghost back to life.

Comment: Seems like OP wants them as a playable ghost.  Is it possible to get an uncontrolled ghost to eat the ambrosia and wouldn't it not result in bringing them back to life?

Comment: @msg45f Aah yes, my mistake - The only way to get playable ghosts is through the Science lab route, and then Ambrosia is used to bring the ghost to life. So my answer is a bit redundant..